# Can't figure out how this LED display was animated

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, shader-nodes, procedural

I'm trying to figure out how [this](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/9mWnfLxoAXM) was done, specifically the animation for the LED screen. The loading bar, the random scrolling numbers (on right), the text that pops up on the bottom left.

What's the workflow for making one of these? Animated UV vectors with custom texture maps? Image Sequence through emissive shaders? I have no clue.

Here a gif animation [from original video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/9mWnfLxoAXM)

[image]

Comment: There are so many ways to achieve a results like this but if you are looking for a tutorial or a breakdown, I think you are in the wrong place. This forum is about solving specific problems that you face while using Blender. For example you could tell us about what you have tried to do so far, what difficulties you encountered and from there we could offer some help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you should do the loading bar animation in another software and then import it in an *Image Texture* node. I've used a simple black and white image instead. Plug your *Image Texture* into the *Factor* of a *Mix Shader* that mixes the dark backround with the emission color. The emission color itself is a mix between a bright red *Emission* and a darker red *Emission*, with a *Noise Texture* as factor in order to create the sparkling:

[image]

Here is what you get if you move the *Location* values of the *Mapping* node of the *Noise Texture*:

[image]

Comment: Ah yes! Ian Hubert has a similar technique. (I came across after writing this), creating a custom image texture with various patterns as a 'flicker controller'.